# Sending a structure containing a Bitmap object via Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, structure

I m trying to send this stucture :

```
 public struct imageBlock

    {
        public uint blockId;
        public Bitmap block;
    }
```

using udp socket
 first I convert the structure to a byte array using this function :

```
 public byte[] getBytes(MyStructure str)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return arr;
    }
```

and I send it :

```
            buffer = crop.getBytes((imageBlock)ImageToBeSent[i]);

            crop.sender(buffer);
```

the problem hapen when I try to receive the structure, I have an exception :

```
                data = client.Receive(ref localEp);

                int size = Marshal.SizeOf(myStructure);
                IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

                Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptr, size);

                myStructure= (MyStructure)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, myStructure.GetType());
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

On the line :

```
  myStructure= (MyStructure)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, myStructure.GetType());
```

I got this Exception :

The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x792a02fe, on thread 0x1860. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Thanks for helping;

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're using unmanaged code and poiners to do this? Unless I'm missing something, it can be done without InteropServices

Comment: Nop, no particular reason, do you have an better idea ?

Comment: Can you tell me specifically what you're trying to do? Is there a reason you're using sockets instead of, say, web services?

Comment: I solved the problem, I just serialized the socket, and it works
thanks guys for helping